# LINQ with grouping and summation

Tags: c#, linq

I need to group on `dept` and `needWeek` and then add `sum` together, add `open` together, and add `closed` together.

This query:

```
var query8 = from q8 in query7
             group q8 by new { q8.q7.dept, q8.needWeek, q8.q7.allCount, q8.q7.openCount, q8.q7.closedCount } into g
             select new
             {
                 dept = g.Key.dept,
                 needWeek = g.Key.needWeek,
                 sum = g.Sum(q8 => g.Key.allCount),
                 open = g.Sum(q8 => g.Key.openCount),
                 closed = g.Sum(q8 => g.Key.closedCount)
             };
```

will return:

```
{ dept = foo, needWeek = 05/20/12, sum = 7, open = 3, closed = 4 }
{ dept = foo, needWeek = 05/20/12, sum = 2, open = 0, closed = 2 }
```

but I need:

```
{ dept = foo, needWeek = 05/20/12, sum = 9, open = 3, closed = 6 }
```

How close am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but you're grouping by all unnecessary fields.  Just group by what is common to all.

```
var query8 =
    from q8 in query7
    group new { q8.q7.allCount, q8.q7.openCount, q8.q7.closedCount }
       by new { q8.q7.dept, q8.needWeek }
       into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.dept,
        g.Key.needWeek,
        sum = g.Sum(x => x.allCount),
        open = g.Sum(x => x.openCount),
        closed = g.Sum(x => x.closedCount),
    };
```

Comment: I don't get the group new by new, can you elaborate, I've never seen it written like that

Comment: The normal group by syntax is: `group [item] by [key]`. The item is the object that is put into the groups and the key you should know. Here, I don't necessarily want to get groups of the `q8` objects, just some properties of them.

Comment: Thx, I'll test that out in LINQPAD.  Can you give an exemple where that might be used ?

Comment: Suppose you had a list of strings and wanted to count how many characters were in a group of strings that have the same first 2 characters. You might do `from s in strings group s by s.Substring(0, 2) into g select new { g.Key, Count = g.Sum(s => s.Length) }`.  But you could also do `from s in strings group s.Length by s.Substring(0, 2) into g select new { g.Key, Count = g.Sum() }`.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to group on `dept` and `needWeek`

So why doesn't your code follow your needs? Why are you grouping by everything?

```
group q8 by new { q8.q7.dept, q8.needWeek } into g
select new
{
    dept = g.Key.dept,
    needWeek = g.Key.needWeek,
    sum = g.Sum(q8 => g.q7.allCount),
    open = g.Sum(q8 => g.q7.openCount),
    closed = g.Sum(q8 => g.q7.closedCount)
};
```